# Permanently storing appended content in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like users to be able to add comments on the last tab of a Shiny app.

I have seen this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259288/shiny-inputs-append-data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com)

This works for my purposes, BUT the appended entries are gone if I close the app and re-open. How can these be stored permanently?

I have replicated the code from the mentioned link, but nothing I have tried actually stores the comments

Comment: If you already have a data base (like pgsql or else) for your shiny app, i would recommend to append the new comments in a table in the database to have it stored permanently. IMO it is the best way to do it. Another option, if you don't have a database, consists in having a .csv file in you app folder. You write new comments in the CSV file and reload the reading of the file to display all the comments in you shiny app.